# What are the default keybindings, and how can I change them?

Tags: neptunia-rebirth-1

I just installed Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth 1 on the PC and jumped straight into the game... which appeared to be a bad idea, because all of the tutorial screens show controls labelled with their controller buttons, not keyboard and mouse buttons.

I've managed to get a bit into the game just by clicking on the on screen controls with my mouse, but now the game is asking me to press what appears to be shoulder pad buttons. Mashing my keyboard at random doesn't appear to work, so what are the default keybindings for this game, and where can I change them?

Comment: Make sure you don't have anything plugged into your computer that the game might think is a controller.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the game isn't very well optimized for keyboard control and favors a gamepad with analog sticks. Key bindings can be changed in the Options > Config menu or more comprehensively by editing the configuration file `Neptune.ini` located in `%userprofile%\Documents\My Games\Idea Factory International, Inc\Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth1`.

The full list of controls as defined in the configuration file are as follows;

```
Input00= Dpad Up
Input01= Dpad Down
Input02= Dpad Left
Input03= Dpad Right
Input04= A Button
Input05= B Button
Input06= X Button
Input07= Y Button
Input08= Back
Input09= Start
Input10= L Shoulder
Input11= R Shoulder
Input12= LStick Up
Input13= LStick Down
Input14= LStick Left
Input15= LStick Right
Input16= RStick Up
Input17= RStick Down
Input18= RStick Left
Input19= RStick Right
```

This is also further discussed on the [Steam Community Forums](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=393853614) which gives further troubleshooting information for if you can't get a particular binding to work.